# read xml file attributes

Tags: php, xml

i'm trying to read rss feed from url,i successfully got the title,description etc.
Now i'm facing problem while reading attributes info.
my xml is like this:

```
<item>
<guid>https://www.edx.org/node/22726</guid>
<title>Managing Projects with Microsoft Project</title>
<link>
 https://www.edx.org/course/managing-projects-microsoft-project-microsoft-cld213x
</link>
<description>
 Want to master project management? Have a project to manage but unsure where to begin? With over 20 million users, Microsoft Project is the go to app for project managers. 
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 06 Jul 2016 16:21:40 -0400</pubDate>
<course:id>course-v1:Microsoft+CLD213x+2T2016</course:id>
<course:code>CLD213x</course:code>
<course:created>Thu, 16 Jun 2016 14:59:55 -0400</course:created>
<course:start>2016-07-11 00:00:00</course:start>
<course:end>2016-12-31 00:00:00</course:end>
<course:self_paced>0</course:self_paced>
<course:length>6 modules</course:length>
<course:prerequisites>
 Basic project management knowledge and skills Basic knowledge and skills using any current Windows® operating system (preferably Windows 10) Competency in using other Microsoft® Office® applications (preferably Office 2016)
</course:prerequisites>
</item>
```

i can easily access title,description,pub date etc but facing problem while accessing `<course:length> <course:id> <course:image-banner> etc`

My php code is

```
<?php
 $rss = simplexml_load_file('https://www.example.org/api/v2/report/course-feed/rss');
echo '<h1>'. $rss->channel->title . '</h1>';
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
 echo '<h2><a href="'. $item->link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h2>";
 echo "<p>" . $item->pubDate . "</p>";
 echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";
```

} 
  ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a namespace problem! First, your document must have an `xmlns:course="//URL"` attribute. Then you can access your `<course:*>` like this:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('https://www.example.org/api/v2/report/course-feed/rss');
$namespaces = $rss->getNamespaces(true);//Add this line
echo '<h1>'. $rss->channel->title . '</h1>';
foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
     echo '<h2><a href="'. $item->link .'">' . $item->title . "</a></h2>";
     echo "<p>" . $item->pubDate . "</p>";
     echo "<p>" . $item->description . "</p>";

     $course = $item->children($namespaces['course']);
     echo $course->id;
     echo $course->prerequisites;
}
```

Comment: i was adding this answer :) got late by 30 sec +1

Comment: @ChetanAmeta This happens to me like 80% of the time :D